# Server on macOS only sometimes accessible from other devices on LAN

Tags: network

I've been trying to get an HTTP server running on my Mac that can receive connections from other devices in my local network. However, it seems this only works with some programs.

My setup is an HTTP server that binds to `0.0.0.0:3000` and then I try to send an HTTP request to the server from a Raspberry Pi (within the same local network) using curl.

I wrote a simple HTTP server in Python & Flask, and one in Rust & Actix Web, but only one (Flask) of them responds to the HTTP request while the Actix Web server runs, the curl command just hangs.

Turning off the firewall seems to have made no difference and I don't think it's a bug in Actix Web as I've also tried Axum, which has the same problem.

Additionally, when the Actix Web or Axum servers start, the popup for allowing incoming connections didn't appear, but it did for the Flask server. Is there something that could be making a server bound to `0.0.0.0` only bind to localhost instead of all interfaces?

Running `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep 3000` returns this for the two programs

```
Python    95673       MY-USERNAME    3u  IPv4 0x4d4507d8356b72ed      0t0    TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

```
rust-api  96081       MY-USERNAME    9u  IPv4 0x4d4507d8356b941d      0t0    TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Are you sure the implementation of the rust-based server is correct? Can you compile/run it on the Pi and try to connect from the Mac?

Comment: I've tried to compile it on the raspberry pi to run it there, but rustc failed due to some linker problem without telling me the reason. I'm not having success with cross-compilation either.

Comment: I got cross compiling to work now and ran the rust server on the Raspberry Pi, and it is reachable from my mac. So it definitely is an issue with my mac.